# YouTube Data Transfer high views

Tags: google-bigquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am using BigQuery Data Transfers to regularly get YouTube Content Owner data. The transfers are running successfully, but for some videos the views I get in the p_content_owner_basic_a3 are much higher than the ones seen in the YouTube Analytics platform.

For instance, for a certain video on 2023-05-17 the total views I receive from the Data Transfer are 10780, while in YouTube Analytics they are 3542. Comparing the video all time summed views confirms that the Analytics views are correct, as they match the number shown in the YouTube platform. The ones from the Data Transfer are ~20000 higher.

For other videos the difference is even larger. For most videos the data is correct. What could be causing the issue?

I've tried triggering manual backfills for the dates with incorrect data thinking perhaps views went down after the initial load if they were bot traffic, but the data remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/transfer-troubleshooting#youtube_transfer_issues:%7E:text=Data%20doesn%27t%20match%20between%20YouTube%20Analytics%20and%20BigQuery%20YouTube%20Transfers), having discrepancies between **BigQuery YouTube Transfers** and **YouTube Analytics** is an expected behavior whereas numbers in YouTube Analytics is treated as **estimated numbers** while **final numbers** are being given in **YouTube Reporting API** which is being used by BigQuery YouTube Transfers to ingest data directly into a BigQuery dataset.
You might have done backfilling again since delayed results are also expected. See notes.

> **Note:** YouTube data for a given day should be made available in YouTube Analytics at most 24-48 hours after the end of that day (sometimes longer). Therefore proceeding generated YouTube Reports and BigQuery Transfers also follow this delay.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the numbers seen in Reporting API are sometimes 3x higher per day. That seems like a bit much, even if the numbers in Analytics are estimated.